# a potentially dangerous request.form value was detected but validateinput(false) not working

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2

I have installed VS2010 and MVC2 and testing a simple form using tinyMCE. When I post the contents of the textarea in tinyMCE I get the dreaded YSD and the message

> "a potentially dangerous....."

I've seen this before so I put the `ValidateInput(false)` on the controller but no joy - I still get the error.

page code in edit.aspx is:

```
    <% using (Html.BeginForm()){ %>

    <!-- Gets replaced with TinyMCE, remember HTML in a textarea should be encoded -->
    <textarea id="elm1" name="mceText" rows="15" cols="80" style="width: 80%">
        &lt;p&gt;
            This is some example text that you can edit inside the
  &lt;strong&gt; TinyMCE editor&lt;/strong&gt;.
    </textarea>

    <br />
    <input type="submit" name="save" value="Submit" />
    <input type="reset" name="reset" value="Reset" />
<%} %>
```

and Controller action is:

```
    [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
    [ValidateInput(false)]
    public ActionResult Edit(string mceText)
    {

        return View();
    }
```

Any thoughts - (I know the code is not complete) been trying this for hours but everyone just says to use  ValidateInput(false)

Comment: Does it work when you disable it globally by putting <pages validateRequest="false"> in web.config?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but that does not work. I read a Phil Haack comment saying it is too late in web.config as controller code has already run.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is why: http://www.asp.net/learn/whitepapers/aspnet4/breaking-changes#0.1__Toc256770147

> The request validation feature in ASP.NET provides a certain level of
>   default protection against cross-site scripting (XSS) attacks. In
>   previous versions of ASP.NET, request validation was enabled by
>   default. However, it applied only to ASP.NET pages (.aspx files and
>   their class files) and only when those pages were executing.
>
> In ASP.NET 4, by default, request validation is enabled for all
>   requests, because it is enabled before the BeginRequest phase of an
>   HTTP request. As a result, request validation applies to requests for
>   all ASP.NET resources, not just .aspx page requests. This includes
>   requests such as Web service calls and custom HTTP handlers. Request
>   validation is also active when custom HTTP modules are reading the
>   contents of an HTTP request.
>
> As a result, request validation errors might now occur for requests
>   that previously did not trigger errors. To revert to the behavior of
>   the ASP.NET 2.0 request validation feature, add the following setting
>   in the Web.config file:

```
<httpRuntime requestValidationMode="2.0" />
```

> However, we recommend that you analyze any request validation errors
>   to determine whether existing handlers, modules, or other custom code
>   accesses potentially unsafe HTTP inputs that could be XSS attack
>   vectors.

Answer (score 5):

A better solution may be to use the tinymce encoding option:

http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Configuration:encoding

```
tinyMCE.init({
        ...
        encoding : "xml"
});
```

then use HttpUtility.HtmlDecode to decode it as required.

See here http://blog.tentaclesoftware.com/archive/2010/07/22/96.aspx

Answer (score 3):

Found it.

need to add `<httpRuntime requestValidationMode="2.0"/>`

in web.config

Comment: Answer did not show up it should say

<httpRuntime requestValidationMode="2.0"/>

Answer (score 3):

With just : encoding: "xml" single quotes are encoded into :  &#39 but ASP.NET validation treats that as a security vulnerability, we have to replace all &#39 to html &amp :

```
tinyMCE.init({
 // ...
 encoding: "xml",
 setup: function (ed) {
 ed.onSaveContent.add(function (ed, o) {
 o.content = o.content.replace(/&#39/g, "&apos");
 });
 }
});
```

Thanks Eddie.

Comment: In TinyMCE 6, use init_instance_callback event instead:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/75068670/3127815