# TinyMCE 6 Replace Text Issue

Tags: tinymce

This issue is specifically for TinyMCE v6 or v5.  I need to replace &#39 with &apos.  I can do this in both v3 and v4.  But I cannot for the life of me get it to work in v5 or v6.  In both v3 and v4, there seems to be some sort of "on save" event that replaces the content before it's sent to the server.

In v3:

```
tinymce.init({
  setup: function(editor) {
    editor.onSaveContent.add(function(editor, e) {
      e.content = content.replace(/&#39/g, "&apos");
    });
  }
});
```

In v4:

```
tinymce.init({
  setup: function(editor) {
    editor.on("SaveContent", function(e) {
      e.content = e.content.replace(/&#39/g, "&apos");
    });
  }
});
```

How do I achieve the same thing in either v5 or v6?  The reason I need to do this is because I get a "dangerous request" error otherwise.

Comment: TinyMCE (by default) would not leave that character encoded other than in an HTML attribute.  What configuration are you using to get TinyMCE to keep that encoding in TinyMCE 5/6?  Can you make a TinyMCE fiddle showing this happening?

Comment: I have encoding set to 'xml'.  It seems TinyMCE is encoding the apostrophe as &#39.  I need it to encode it as &apos.  Again, this is doable in both v3 and v4, but I cannot find a way to do it in v5 and v6.  This is resulting in clients not being able to use an apostrophe.

Comment: I don't see TinyMCE doing any encoding of any apostrophe at all in TinyMCE 6 even with setting `encoding: 'xml'` in the configuration: fiddle.tiny.cloud/Xdiaab/1

Answer (score 1):

This works for tinyMCE 6:

```
init_instance_callback: function (editor) {
    editor.on('PostProcess', function (e) {
      e.content = e.content.replace(/\'/g, "&apos;");
    });
},
```

https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/tinymce/6/events/

Answer (score 0):

@michael Fromin, I'm not allowed to comment yet, so I have to use the answer field unfortunately.
I run into the same problem.
if you add a submit button to your fiddle:

https://fiddle.tiny.cloud/Xdiaab/1

```
<form method="post" action="dump.php">
    <textarea name="content">
        <p>This is an apostrophe (#39):  &#39;</p>
        <p>This is an apostrophe (native):  '</p>
        <p>This is an apostrophe (apos):  &apos;</p>
        
    </textarea>
    <input type="submit" name="Save" value="Save">
</form>
```

then you can post the content and see the result:

[image: Post Dump]

IIS / ASPX is throwing error on this, we would like/need to replace this value with &apos.

for now, i have fixed the problem by replacing **&#39** with **&apos** in **tinymce.min.js**
It works now, but this is a workaround..
Thanks a lot.

Comment: This works but it is really a workaround and gets lost when you update tinyMCE. So I tried more and found a better solution.